# I am implementing api with digest authentication with headers,not getting responce from below code

Tags: objective-c

```
-(void)httpPostWithCustomDelegate
{
    NSString *st = @"Digest username=\"admin\", realm=\"REST API\", nonce=\"1\", uri=\"/canteen/restserver/index.php/welcome/login\", qop=auth, nc=2, cnonce=\"2\", response=\"0097667c159d30166fb195909955ebac\", opaque=\"1\"";
    NSDictionary *headers = @{ @"authorization":st,@"cache-control":@"no-cache"};

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://canteen.mostlovedcountry.com/restserver/index.php/welcome/login"];
    NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString * params =@"empcode=divya.p@ecreeds.com&password=cc03e747a6afbbcbf8be7668acfebee5";
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [urlRequest setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];

    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                       completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                           NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

                                                    NSLog(@"%@", dic);
                                        NSLog(@"Response:%@",response);
                                                           NSLog(@"%@",error);
                                                           if(error == nil)
                                                           {
                                                               NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                               NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);
                                                           }

                                                       }];
    [dataTask resume];

}
```

Comment: "No response", meaning? Is the `completionHandler` called? Is `dic` nil? (You didn't put an `NSError` parameter in the `NSJSONSerialization`). Is `data` nil? What's happening exactly?

Comment: I run your code it shows response like this Data = {"status":false,"error":"Invalid credentials"}

Comment: if u hit the api in postman with form data(empcode:divya.p@ecreeds.com,password:cc03e747a6afbbcbf8be7668acfebee5) and digest authentication headers,u will get user login details.but from the code its showing invalid credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution of digest authentication with headers
-(void)loginApi
{

```
NSDictionary *headers = @{@"content-type": @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",  @"authorization": @"Digest username=\"admin\", realm=\"REST API\", nonce=\"1\", uri=\"/restserver/index.php/welcome/login\", qop=auth, nc=1, cnonce=\"1\", response=\"e35d1ebfcfa17a119ee0b45c6703cb8e\", opaque=\"1\"", @"cache-control": @"no-cache" };



NSMutableData *postData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"empcode=divya.p@ecreeds.com"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&password=cc03e747a6afbbcbf8be7668acfebee5"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://canteen.mostlovedcountry.com/restserver/index.php/welcome/login"]

                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy

                                                   timeoutInterval:10.0];


[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];

[request setHTTPBody:postData];



NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request

                                            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                                if (error) {

                                                    NSLog(@"%@", error);

                                                } else {

                                                    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;

                                                    NSLog(@"%@", httpResponse);

                                                    NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

                                                    NSLog(@"%@", dic);

                                                }

                                            }];

[dataTask resume];
```

}